# Can a god not appear and interfere on Golarion?

Tags: religions-and-deities, golarion

Is there any source that says that a god can not directly appear on Golarion? We were talking about some bad guys in the Golarion history and I was wondering, why e.g. Torag did not just appear and clash the whispering tyrant. One of our players said that this is not possible since the gods have an agreement that they do not directly interfere. But he could not remember the source.

I have looked for something like this in the books but could not find anything. Can anyone of you confirm this (with a source)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, they can.

But they hardly do anymore for mysterious reasons.

There is one famous intervention on the [Wrath of the Righteous](http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/paizoInc/pathfinder/adventurePath/wrathOfTheRighteous) adventure path (spoilers ahead):

> [Iomedae](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Iomedae) shows personally to boss the PCs around for a short while.

PS: I have not read the AP other than a few spoilers on the messageboards, as i plan to play it sometime. If not, i will wait until my players show interest on playing it before reading it.

About the *Whispering Tyrant* ([Tar-Baphom](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Tar-Baphon)), there is a lot of background on that. The deities used [their heralds](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Arazni) to help mortals on that battle, because if any *good* deity showed up personally to help fighting against him, others *evil* deities would show up to stand for him.

Answer (score 1):

(Don't have my book here, but I was a priest of Rovagug)

**Yes but no** When Asmodeus crafted the pact that bound Rovagug, he added such a clause in the contract signed by all the gods.

**Yes** The gods can and do interfere with Golarion through their agents (priests, worshippers) by sending them visions and spells.

**No** Torag can't just show up and act directly. In WotRighteous, a deity shows up and tells the PCs what to do but does not actually do it herself.

Then again, If Asmodeus wrote the contract... you know there are exception clauses...

Comment: Signed by all the gods *at that time*. It's important because on that same campaign, a demon lord (which is a minor deity) is physically on the material plane.

Comment: Those late-coming upstarts are just that! :P

Comment: That is probably the reason why Iomedae is not bound by that contract. She passed the starstone test in  3832 AR, while rovagug was imprisoned much earlier than that, on -3923 AR.

Comment: However, this is simply speculation.

Comment: The "Yes but no" part is what I was looking for. It would be nice if you could add a source when you have time to.